# Google Analytics on Android gives avg site duration: 00:00:00

Tags: android, google-analytics, duration

This is how I designed my Google Analytics to work on my app:

Every activity extends `TrackedFragmentActivity` or any other fragmentActivity which extends `TrackedFragmentActivity`.

TrackedFragmentActivity is:

```
public class TrackedFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

    public void startAnalytics(String pageName) {
        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

        tracker.startNewSession("UA-CODE-HERE", this);
        tracker.trackPageView(pageName);
        tracker.dispatch();
    }   
}
```

and every activity has a `super.startAnalytics("pagenameHere")` call in the `onCreate`.

Now, every activity gets properly tracked and everything, but duration-related data are completely messed up:

```
Pages / Visit: 1.07
Avg. Visit Duration: 00:00:00
Bounce Rate: 94.63%
```

I was calling `stopTracker()` `onDestroy` and I though it was its fault for this behavior, therefore I tried to remove it, but I get exactly the same problem.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was calling this method:
    tracker.startNewSession("UA-CODE-HERE", this);

every time a new activity was loaded. So I just added a very stupid static boolean to call the method only the first time. Does anyone have a better solution?

the new code is:

```
public class TrackedFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private static GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    private static boolean hasStarted = false;

    public void startAnalytics(String pageName) {

        if(!hasStarted) {
            tracker.startNewSession("UA-CODE-HERE", this);
            hasStarted = true;
        }

        tracker.trackPageView(pageName);
        tracker.dispatch();

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a normal behavior. My understanding is that Google Analytics on Android platform is limited to logging simple events.